# Stuck trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

Tags: ubuntu, repository

When I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 I I got stuck. While upgrading, it shows: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded`.

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

I tried `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, and it says the same line already exists in sources.list.

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

I found a solution on the internet. Replace this line: `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse partner` with this line: `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner`. But the same line was already present in my `sources.list`.

Now I'm unable to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update
```

Replace `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse partner` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (if it exists) with `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner` and run `sudo apt update` again to refresh the list of available software.

Answer (score 0):

The `ubuntu-release-upgrader` will re-generate your `sources.list` and the third party repository under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` with the new Ubuntu codname `focal`.

Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, it should contain (at least):

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main 
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main
```

Here is a sources.list example with `restricted  universe multiverse` enabled.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted  universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, Solved it.**
The problem was here ..
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and **1 not upgraded.**

I got to know
The following packages have been kept back:
**git-el** in my case check yours

 :~$ sudo apt list --upgradeable

**I got this as output**
Listing... Done
git-el/bionic 1:2.29.2-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1 all [upgradable from:
1:2.29.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1]
N: There are 3 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.

this is 1 which is not upgraded.
Thus try to remove

:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove git-el

 and then  
 :~$ sudo apt update

  :~$ sudo apt upgrade

finally you can upgrade to 20.04  
:~$ update-manager -d

I did nothing in  /etc/apt/sources.list as it was fine.